# JPA transactional proxy within a thread issue

Tags: spring, multithreading, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my `Controller` I have injected (`@Autowired`) this `Service`, which implements `Runnable` (I need multi-threading) and I call it like so:

```
Thread t = new Thread(service);
t.start();
t.join();
```

Then, in my `Service`'s `run()` I call this `Repository` (simple `JPARepository`), which is injected in `Service` also with `@Autowired`:

```
repository.save(someEntity);
```

The problem is that it doesn't persist the entity with `id=1`. The transactional proxy (and Hibernate connection pool) is initialized after the unsuccessful saving of the first entity. After that, it works fine.

Can anyone point me to the right direction with my issue: **how to force the Thread to initialize the Hibernate transactional proxy before persisting the first entity**?

Comment: try using entitymanager (which is thread safe) https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-entitymanager

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed...

Comment: can u run it with debug mode (`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`) and show us the relevant logs

Comment: Ill try it tomorrow, not on my computer right now

Comment: My `run()` is annotated with `@Async` and `@Transactional`

Comment: You dont get any errors for the first one?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai No, I don't.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to start the thread after Spring context is refreshed. This is safer because all your beans may be in an inconsistent state.

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void handleContextStart() {
   // ...
}
```